# How do I make a read-only textbox that selects all text when tapped?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a textbox look like a textblock (no white background or anything) so that I can display resulting text and numbers in it. When the user taps on the text I want the whole result to be highlighted for easy copy/pasting. This is for a Windows Phone 8 Application. Thanks!

I've tried using this:

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But it makes it so that everything is black or invisible until you tap on the text to highlight it.

Comment: Dont know much abt windows phone 8 apps but have u tried the ReadOnly Property?

Comment: I've been using the ReadOnly property but with no luck, @GrantWinney I posted more code.

Answer (score 0):

To make it look like `TextBlock` you have to set `IsReadOnly` property to true and modify control style (template) for `ReadOnly` visual state as shown below:

```
<!-- namespace declarations
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
-->

 <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxAsTextBlock">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF99C1E2" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#00000000" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(LinearGradientBrush.Opacity)" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EditModeLeftBorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Opacity="0" Background="#5EC9C9C9" />
                            <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Width="2" x:Name="EditModeLeftBorderElement" Grid.Column="0" />
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Grid.Column="1" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Background="#A5F7F7F7" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" 
                     PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                            <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
                            <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To select text on focus assign following event handler to `GotFocus` event:

```
private static void OnTextBoxFocused(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jozef, I've been trying to use the code you've suggested but I've ran into some problems. It seems anything with "vsm:" in front of it won't compile, and this <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean> shows an error saying "the type Boolean was not found."

Comment: Sorry @davekats, my bad, I forgot to add xml namespace declarations, see the updated version.

Comment: Ah that fixed it. But the text is still not showing up in the textblock, it's all black unless I tap to highlight it

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted - to have it look as a TextBlock and highlight the text at the moment user taps is?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant for the text to be viewable in the textbox, like a normal textblock's text would. And then when it's tapped it's highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question.

The style:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CopyPasteTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentElement" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And the textbox:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="396" Margin="31,231,41,106">
            <TextBox TextAlignment="Left" 
                 FontSize="30" 
                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                 Grid.Row="2" 
                 Foreground="White" 
                 Name="resultbox" 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                 BorderThickness="0" 
                 Style="{StaticResource CopyPasteTextBox}" 
                 GotFocus="resultbox_GotFocus"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```